# Save cell containing different length vectors to text file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, text, vector, cell-array

I am trying to save a cell array containing different length column vectors to a text file in MATLAB, but I am a bit stuck.

```
cell_structure = {[1;2;3;...546] [1;2;3;...800] [1;2;3;...1011] [1;2;3;...1118] [1;2;3;...1678]}
```

I tried using the following code:

```
   fid = fopen( 'myFile.txt', 'w' ) ;
 for cId = 1 : numel( cell_structure )
    fprintf( fid, '%f ', cell_structure{cId} ) ;
    fprintf( fid, '\r\n' ) ;
 end
```

The problem is when I open the text file the column vectors are saved as row vectors and their length is limited to 545. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us an example of the output you would like?

Comment: Have you tried `dlmwrite` with `'-append'` property?

Comment: @Crowley I have tried using dlmwrite('test.txt',cell{i},'-append') and then incrementing i. However it adds all the columns vectors into one column in the text file, I want each column vector in the cell array to be saved in individual columns in the text file.

Comment: @ jgrant I would like the output to be a tab delimited text file where each column vector from the cell array is saved in separate columns of the text file.

Comment: There's some misunderstanding here. I tried the code You mentioned and I got file with multiple rows containig numbers 1,2,3,... Also I can see only row vectors in your example. Columnar vectors are `[1;2;3;...]`.

Comment: @Crowley The cell structure in my question is supposed to contain column vectors, I didn't know how to properly represent them. I would like to save the column vectors from my cell into separate columns of a text file. Sorry about the confusion I have made an edit to my question now.

Comment: @JamesArcher This edit makes it proper. Check my answer wheter it works as you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Elijah Rockers idea to pad out the shorter column vectors so they are all the same length. And Crowley pointed out that dmlwrite and cvswrite cannot handle empty cells. I found a function that can handle empty cells:

https://github.com/mkoohafkan/UCBcode-Matlab/blob/master/OtherPeoplesFunctions/dlmcell.m

And here is my code to pad out and the save data.

```
    for k = 1:max(cellfun('length',cell)); %longest column vector length
    for j = 1:length(cell); % number of colum vctors
        if k > length(cell{j}); % if the index is longer than colum vector length
           new_cell{k,j} = []; % pad vector
        else
         new_cell{k,j} = cell{j}(k); %otherwise add to array
        end
    end
end
dlmcell('test.txt',new_cell,',')
```

It works like a charm, all of the column vectors in the cell array are now saved in separate columns of the text file.

Answer (score 1):

Your first iteration of the `for` loop prints the ENTIRE first array, in cell_structure. It doesn't matter whether this array is a row or a column vector, since you're using fprintf(), it's going to print each element out, one after another.

This is a little trickier than I can manage at work right now... but you will need to pad your shorter vectors to match the length of your largest.

Then:

```
for k = 1:size_of_largest_vector
    for j = 1:total_number_of_columns
         new_cell{k,j} = cell_structure{j}(k)
    end
end
```

This will give you an array of all your column vectors.

Then, use a space delimited `csvwrite()` to write the columns.

Comment: just saw that you want separate colums for each column vector... let me try to work that out and i'll edit

Comment: Sorry the confusion about defining the cell structure as rows vectors, in real life they are column vectors.